# How to show the results in foreach as static result using php?

Tags: php

I have tried to show the result as static if data is not there like the following code. If result is not there for time 9 I want show the result empty in column.
The following records will show first 10 records from the database table.

Dynamic results from database

```php
$n=10; 
 
$slice = array_splice($results, 0, $n);


foreach ($slice as $result) { 
  //print_r($result);
  $date = date('h:i', strtotime($result['lotdatetime']));
  ?>

  <tr>
    
    <td><?php 
    if($date=='09:00'){
      echo $date.' KOLKATA';
    } else if($date=='10:00'){
      echo $date.' KOLKATA';
    } else if($date=='10:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='11:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    } else if($date=='11:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='12:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    } else if($date=='12:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='01:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    } else if($date=='01:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='02:00'){
      echo $date.' KOLKATA';
    } else if($date=='03:00'){
      echo $date.' KL';
    } else if($date=='03:15'){
      echo $date.' BSE';
    } else if($date=='03:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='04:00'){
      echo $date.' KOLKATA';
    } else if($date=='05:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    } else if($date=='05:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='06:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    } else if($date=='06:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='07:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    } else if($date=='07:30'){
      echo $date.' LOTO';
    } else if($date=='08:00'){
      echo $date.' PJ';
    }else {
      echo $date;
    }?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['lot_no']; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

```
Output: 

    Time            Result
    09:00 KOLKATA   999
```

```
Expected output ( if data is not available but i have to show the time alone)

    09:00 KOLKATA   ---
    10:00 KOLKATA   ----
    etc,...
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: it seems that your database is returning only rows where lot_no is there. So you have to modify your query to return the values. Probably (but it's only a guess) you are using a INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN in your query?

Comment: Also I'd suggest to change the if with a switch, it can be hugely simplified because with a switch you can add different cases to the same instruction (so you can group all the KOLKATA cases and so on)

Comment: If you want it to show the times that aren't in the results, you'll have to iterate through the times and find the results inside of that loop instead of iterating through the results.   If instead you mean that the times will still be in the results without the lot_no, you just need a check on your final td to see if it is set and print the dashes you desire if not.

Comment: I want to show default time list with no data

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` will iterate over `$slice` entries, but you want to show data even if that is empty.

In such cases use dummy-data.

Try something like:

```php
$n = 10;

$slice = array_splice($results, 0, $n);

$slice[] = array_slice([
    ['lotdatetime' => '09:00'],
    ['lotdatetime' => '10:00'],
    ['lotdatetime' => '10:30'],

    // ... And so on (you get what the idea) ...

], count($slice));

// ...
```

And in your `foreach` you only need to provide default for "`lot_no`" field, like:

```php
// ...

    <td><?php echo $result['lot_no'] ?? '---'; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: How to run as foreach loop

Comment: @mike You maybe did not get what I meant with "`// ...`", the first "`// ...`" marks where your `foreach` code should be, as I only wrote my changes to your code (please imagine your `foreach` is at above's end ;-) ).